# Is there a configuration file for Marklogic where I can set the default folders for new forests

Tags: storage, marklogic

In Azure the CENTOS default drive for /var/opt (where forest go by default) is only 30 GIG. If you install DataHub even if you set the project folder to /data/dataHub which is on /dev/sdc it creates all the storage under /var/opt which will fill with minimal data. This is clearly not ideal. I assume I am missing something and there is a config file somewhere where I can change the defaults for database creation so my data is separate from my software.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MarkLogic uses a configuration file referenced at startup to determine where the data should go.  If you need to the default data directory to be in a different location you should create/edit /etc/marklogic.conf and set a value for MARKLOGIC_DATA_DIR

```
# where MarkLogic keeps its data
export MARKLOGIC_DATA_DIR=/dev/sdc
```

When you restart MarkLogic it will use that as the new default location.  Alternatively, you could make the mount point for the device /var/opt/MarkLogic or /var/opt/MarkLogic/Forests and leave the default settings in place.

Comment: Instead of mounting a device directly under /var/opt/MarkLogic, you could also mount it elsewhere, and then create a symlink from /var/opt/MarkLogic pointing to a folder inside the mount. You could even stop the MarkLogic service, move the entire folder to the other location, create the symlink, and start MarkLogic again. If done right, it should not notice any difference. Though, it might be wise to coordinate with Support for additional guidance.

Comment: Michael's answer works well. This is easily done before installation and you immediately get your data where you need it to be. SImple and self documenting.

Comment: if we add a symlink from /var/opt/MarkLogic to new mount, and if /var/opt/MarkLogic does not have enough space, then inside monitoring dashboard under disk space you will see warnings as per the size of /var/opt/MarkLogic only.